# Whole text not exported in pdf using aspose word template

Tags: aspose.words

I have a scenatio to export a 25000 characters text , which is does not have any space break between character. it mean single word with 250000 length . but realtime a word length cannot be more then 25. Anyhow the text should have exported into pdf using Aspose word template. but it doesnot export 25000 length , instead export 4578 characters into pdf , remaining are discarded in pdf. but i could get the 25000 length character in my code before calling that pdf export method using aspose.

But the text are properly exported into pdf , if you give positive scenario text upto any characters length .
Let me know, is there any solution why the text are discarded , if gives contineous text without break?

Comment: Aspose.Words mimics the behavior of MS Word. Please share your input Word document here for testing. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

Please use CompatibilityOptions.GrowAutofit property as shown below to get the desired output.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "SupervisionReportTemplate - Copy.docx");

DataTable table = new DataTable("SupervisorComment");
table.Columns.Add("GeneralVisitComment", typeof(string));

var newRow = table.NewRow();
newRow["GeneralVisitComment"] = File.ReadAllText(MyDir + "25000 contineous character length.txt", Encoding.Unicode);
table.Rows.Add(newRow);

doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(table);
doc.CompatibilityOptions.GrowAutofit = true;

doc.Save(MyDir + "18.4.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.